# How to use IAM role to rotate the AWS secret keys in Spring boot Application for a task

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-iam, secret-manager, ecs-taskdefinition

I want to use an IAM role for using AWS services like S3, SNS etc in my task rather than specifying the secret keys of the user.

I have seen this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-iam-roles.html but I am not sure about how to implement this in the spring boot environment.

Currently, I have the keys in properties file which are used for bean creation at the startup and the same bean is used for all the AWS service interaction (which I believe is not a good practice).

Can someone suggest the way to achieve this.

Comment: If you use IAM instance profiles, you do not set keys. It's "magic" from the SDK. You don't set any credentials in your app and it just "works" (unless you explicitly coded your app to require keys).

Comment: Yep, instance roles is the way to do it. No Keys or Secrets to store. Its not a spring boot thing. The application running on the container will inherit the permissions of the service role assigned to that container.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will need to create an IAM role that is usable by ecs. Grant it the permissions you previously used with the IAM key.

Then in your ECS task definition set the [task execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html) to the role ARN.

Finally make sure your code removes references to IAM key and IAM secret. If these are not specified (and assuming you're using the SDK) then the SDK will check the IAM role credentials automatically.

Comment: Some additional documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-iam-roles.html